# Radio button issue - selection disappearing while clicking outside

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I've created a radio button group and its working perfectly except, when we click on a radio button it shows the selection but when we click outside of the radio button that selection is disappearing. Can anyone help me to solve this?

```
Link to jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/viveknath322/evzsn8y6/
```

Comment: Actually, your selection is not disappearing. The check mark is still in the right radio, but barely visible due to its black colour. So you have an error somewhere in your CSS which only applies to `:focus`, and not on `:checked`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is using the ":checked" attribute instead of the ":focus" attribute used currently.

Change

```
.c-form__checkbox:focus + .r-form__label .c-form__checkbox-square,
.r-form__radio:focus + .r-form__label .r-form__radio-circle {
  stroke: #31CC89;
  fill: #31CC89;
}
```

to

```
.c-form__checkbox:checked + .r-form__label .c-form__checkbox-square,
.r-form__radio:checked + .r-form__label .r-form__radio-circle {
  stroke: #31CC89;
  fill: #31CC89;
}
```

Focus causes to be not triggered anymore as soon as you click outside the radio button, as you are then focusing on another element.

Comment: Thank you so much, now its fine